# Nginx rewrite rules for AngularJS and html5mode enabled

Tags: nginx, routes, url-rewriting, angularjs

so far,i am building AngularJS application served with nginx. I had rails in the middle and i came with `rewrite ^/(?!assets) / last;`  rewrite rule (rewrite everything expect those beginning with assets), so far it was working - with rails:

```
   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name ies.local;
      root /home/jk/Projects/ies12/webapp/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env development;
      rewrite ^/(?!assets) / last;
    }
```

But by today, i left rails and i need to extend this rule..

If I do something like

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name webapp.local;
  root /home/jk/Projects/webapp;
  rewrite_log on;

  rewrite ^/(?!angular) / last;
  rewrite ^/(?!angular-ui) / last;
}
```

having webapp/index.html only file
and getting:

```
*1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to 
"/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: webapp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "webapp.local"
```

Comment: Maybe merge it in one rule: `rewrite ^/(\?!angular(-ui){0,1}) / last;`

Comment: yeah, sure yours regexp will work. But finally i broke it. Mainly i had to rewrite ^/(?!angular) /index.html last; and my bad was <script src="angular" instead of <script src="/angular" in my files and i think this somehow caused the cycle..